# Magento Checkout Error: redirects to shopping cart

Tags: php, javascript, magento, magento-1.7

When customer clicks register button at checkout, the register fields show momentarily, then it directly redirects to the shopping cart.

This only happens when guest checkout is disabled.

Here is the error log:

```
2013-05-31T20:32:10+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:10+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:10+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:10+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:10+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:11+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:12+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:19+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:19+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:20+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:25+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:36+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:36+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:36+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:36+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:36+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:37+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:37+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:37+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:37+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:37+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 39
2013-05-31T20:32:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_width  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:42+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _big_image_height  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml on line 57
2013-05-31T20:32:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _lasscountfirst  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/page/template/toplinks.phtml on line 49
2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _imgUrl  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/exdress/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 47
2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Varien_Object::addData() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/code/local/CDD/CustomWidget/Block/List.php on line 56 and defined  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 243
2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 245
2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Creating default object from empty value  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/code/local/CDD/CustomWidget/Block/List.php on line 75
2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Creating default object from empty value  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/code/local/CDD/CustomWidget/Block/List.php on line 75
2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Creating default object from empty value  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/code/local/CDD/CustomWidget/Block/List.php on line 75
2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Creating default object from empty value  in /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/code/local/CDD/CustomWidget/Block/List.php on line 75
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is reason of you issue:

> 2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1
>   passed to Varien_Object::addData() must be of the type array, string
>   given, called in
>   /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/app/code/local/CDD/CustomWidget/Block/List.php
>   on line 56 and defined  in
>   /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on
>   line 243 2013-05-31T20:32:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument
>   supplied for foreach()  in
>   /home/bulb/domains/bulb-store.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on
>   line 245

Try disable this module CDD/CustomWidget, you can easy do this go to app/etc/modules and find .xml of this module and then setup < active >false< / active >.